# solve an inequality with Log terms

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

I get the following inequality to solve (after some manipulations/transformations). Special I want to write $x$ or $y$ in terms of other parameters. I even tried to convert this into form which we can solve using the Lambert W function, but I could not do it. It seems difficult for me at this stage.

If someone has smart tips, please share with me. 
$$y\ln\left[1+an\left(\frac{1-x}{n-x}\right)\right]>\ln\left[1+abxy\right]$$
where $x\in[0,1];~~y\in[0,\infty);~ a,b>0;~ n>1$.